# Custom CollectionView Layout - Apple Doc suggests restriction to a single cell type?

Tags: ios, layout, uicollectionview

Browsing the documentation for [Creating Custom Layouts](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CreatingCustomLayouts/CreatingCustomLayouts.html), I've come across this ambiguous statement:

*"The process for creating the attributes objects for supplementary views in your custom layout is nearly identical to the process for cells, but differs in that a custom layout can have multiple types of supplementary views **but is restricted to one type of cell**."*

As it is perfectly possible to register multiple cell classes in a UICollectionView, and use a custom layout, I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

Any insight appreciated!